# How to connect to snowflake using browser client in case of privatelink

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

What URL do we need to use  to connect to snowflake using browser client when we have private link setup for snowflake? We have setup AWS privatelink to connect to Snowflake so that we can avoid traffic over the internet. Any input regarding this would be great if someone has setup this. I get 403 Forbidden error when I use privatelink dns from browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AWS PrivateLink](https://aws.amazon.com/privatelink/) is a great way for Snowflake customers on AWS to get private connectivity over AWS networking backbone. For example, you can run server tools such as Tableau server in your VPC, and connect to Snowflake without going over the internet.
Here's the high-level process flow to enable it for your account.

1. Enable PrivateLink in your VPC following AWS documentation.
2. File support case with Snowflake to enable PrivateLink for your account. Include your AWS account Id in the support case.
3. After enabling the feature, Snowflake support will provide back with 3 pieces of information a) Snowflake privatelink url, b) DNS record, and c) ip address to restrict public url access to your Snowflake account.
4. Set up DNS based on the DNS record provided to you above. Setup AWS security group policies to allow access to Snowflake privatelink url ports 443 and 80 (for OCSP).
5. Create a network policy in Snowflake allowing only the ip address provided above by support.
6. Verification: From your VPC, spin up an EC2 instance, and login to Snowflake privatelink url through the browser running on EC2. Or, use snowsql commandline tool for verification from inside the VPC.

Additional security best practice:
Setup [S3 endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-gateway.html) in your VPC. This will ensure that S3 access from your VPC goes over AWS backbone instead of internet. Note that Snowflake drivers connect directly to S3 for getting large resultsets or if you are using PUT commands to load data.

Also, refer to official doc for this topic https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/admin-security-privatelink.html

Here's [high-level diagram of how it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79lyg.png).

Note: Private connectivity from your corporate network to AWS VPC is a separate topic, and you can configure it using AWS Direct Connect or AWS VPN. That configuration is independent of Snowflake, and you should be able to work directly with AWS to enable it.

[Vikas Jain](https://www.linkedin.com/in/vikasjainpublic/) | Security Product Management | Snowflake